# jquery mobile, local storage json

Tags: jquery, json, mobile, local-storage

i am using jquery mobile and i am saving my json object in local storage (longitude and latitude) and i want to use longitude and latitude to show map but i don't know how to get value from local storage.

So far i have this but it returns undefined

```
  $('#map').click(function(){

   if(navigator.geolocation){

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( display);
   }
});


function display( position){

  var div = $('#show');

  var i= position.coords.localStorage.getItem('longitude') +","+ 

  position.coords.localStorage.getItem('latitude');

  $(div).append(i);

  var imgu = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center="
  +i+"&zoom=15&size=400x300&sensor=false";

   $("#show").html("<img src='"+imgu+"'/>");


}
```

Comment: write your json also to clerify all things

Comment: {"c":[ {  "longitude": "43.5920° N", "latitude": "79.6432° W"  }    ]   } 
This is what i have in my json file.